# convert xml (into iob2 format for NER/ABSA)

Tags: python, xml-parsing, nlp, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition

I have an xml like this:
< sentences >
 
< sentence id="1">
< text > Pizza is great< / text >
< aspectTerms >
< aspectTerm to="5" from="1" polarity="positive" term="pizza"/>
(SemEval ABSA dataset)

and I would like to convert it like this:
pizza B
is O
 great O

i.e. extract the sentences from the xml and place each word in a new line. 
Achieving this would already help me.

Ideally, there would also be a blank line between the last word of a sentence and the first of the next sentence. 
And in the best case, there would be a second column next to the words with an IOB2-tag (i.e. O for all words other than the xml-indicated aspectTerms, B for the aspect [or I for composed aspect terms])

the idea is to use this converted file as training data for a sequence labeling task (to extract aspect terms from sentences, somewhat similar to NER)

I tried to achieve it with ElementTree but wasn't successful.

Sorry for this newbie question - any tips would help :)

Comment: show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I was just able to print all sentences in the child "text" (with find all)